# Is it possible to decompile .asmx file from client side to get the code?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

Is it possible to get the source code of a webservice asmx file. An android app calling the service can be de-compiled to fetch the source code. This exposes the code which is a problem.

Can the service be similarly de-compiled from client side.

To secure Android native code, code can be obfuscated, or token based authentication can be used to avoid hacking.

But if my asmx source code is exposed to the client, then the complete server side code is shared.

Is there any way to restrict this and secure web service.

Comment: `.asmx` files, themselves, aren't the *output* of a compiler stage - they're the input. So there's nothing to "decompile" about them.

Comment: Sure, logon to the webserver with RDP, navigate to the folder where ASP.NET stores [the compiled assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx), and open these in [ILSPY](http://ilspy.net/). Hack completed.

Comment: I want to de-compile and get the source code from client side.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible. Plenty of vulnerabilities such as [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Relative_Path_Traversal) can be exploited to disclose source, or worse. But, without such a vulnerability, it should not be possible to download the raw ASMX file from a properly configured server.